# Dismiss Messages View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

I have an iMessage Extension in swift that is in expanded presentationStlye when a user taps a button. Once this button is tapped, it should dismiss the view entirely or at least return to compact mode. I am not sure what is wrong. Here is didTransition being called from my button:

```
self.didTransition(to: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.compact)
```

and the action:

```
override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {

    guard presentationStyle == .expanded else { return }
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {

    }
}
```

But this is not working. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the right func to call is that one :

```
requestPresentationStyle(MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle)
```

You can call it like this in your `MSMessageAppViewController` :

```
self.requestPresentationStyle(.compact)
```

You don't need to override anything ;) Hope this will help you!

Note: have a look to the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msmessagesappviewcontroller

It will help you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These function will help to move from one transition state to another in MSMessagesViewController:-

```
requestPresentationStyle(.expanded)    
requestPresentationStyle(.compact)
```

Above method will invoke willTransition and didTransition:-

```
  override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
```

//Here we can check the presentationStyle and move the Controller according to need . i.e

```
    let controller: UIViewController
    if presentationStyle == .compact {
        controller = instantiateCompactController()
    }
    else {
        controller = instantiateExpandController()
    }
    //and then Present Controller
    }
```

For More Information : https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/224/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `dismiss()` function to dismiss an expanded `MSMessagesAppViewController` entirely.

Note this isn't the same as `dismiss(animated:)` which dismisses a modally presented vc. [Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessagesappviewcontroller/1649179-dismiss).